# Yii2 join relations with 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have 4 tables, say table A, B, C, D.
Somewhat like:

**Table**

```
A - a_id, a_name.
B - b_id, a_id, b_name.
C - c_id, b_id, d_id.
D - d_id, d_name
```

How can I get the table D object for a corresponding primary key value of A ie. if value of id in A is 20, I need all data from d table corresponding to that in yii2.

`A -> B` is one to many.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's better to give real world example for better understanding. And I think naming primary key of the same table as `id` (not `a_id` for `a` table) is better practice.

This can be done using relation chain. For example if we have 3 models: `Test`, `Question` and `Answer` (test has many questions and question has many answers), having an answer model we can access test model like so:

```
$answer = Answer:findOne(20); // id must exist
$test = $answer->question->test;
```

But it doesn't work vice versa with has many, because we need to know specific model to continue chain, so we can't write something like:

```
$answer = $test->question->answer
```

Only `$test->questions` and `$question->answers` are acceptable.

This is exactly your case. Read [Working with Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data) article in official docs for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I'll share the code part and real world db part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got a 4 or even more relation situation same as you, table as these:

```
Link - id, SalesItemId.
SalesItem - id, SoId, ItemName
SalesOrder - id, SalesId, OrderNo
User - id, ManagerId, Name 
User - id, Name
```

** the User table I have related 2 times as I need to get the manager name of the user

In `Link` model, I got these methods:

```
public function getLinkSalesitem() {
    return $this->hasOne(Salesitem::className(), ['id' => 'SalesItemId']);
}
public function getLinkSalesorder() {
    return $this->hasOne(Salesorder::className(), ['id' => 'SoId'])
            ->via('linkSalesitem');
            // ->viaTable('salesitem', ['id' => 'SalesItemId']); //either this line or above are the same
}
public function getLinkSales() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'SalesId'])
            ->via('linkSalesorder'); 
}
public function getLinkManager() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'ManagerId'])
            ->via('linkSales'); 
}
```

In the view file, I just retrieve the the Manager name by

```
$model->linkManager->Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use relations then first you have to make sure that table A is Connect to table D through some table in you case table A is connected to table B with a_id,table B is connected with table C with b_id and table C and table D are connected with through d_id in table c.
Now if you want data from table D then you have to make relations
First make relations

```
      public function getB(){
return $this->hasOne(B::className(),['a_id' => 'a_id'])
    }
public function getC(){
```

return $this->hasOne(C::className(),['b_id' => 'b_id'])
}
Now you want data from A and D which is connected through relation C so you have to make relation like

```
    public function getD(){
return $this->hasOne(D::className(),['d_id' => 'a_id'])->via('c')
}
```

First find A

```
$model = A::findOne(20);
echo isset($model->c)?$model->c->d_name:'';
```